# sprintf() function changing the input arguments

Tags: c

My code is following

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 10;
  char c[3];

  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  sprintf(c, "%d", i);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Result of it's execution:

10

10

Great, make scene. Let's make char array too small.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 100;
  char c[3];

  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  sprintf(c, "%d", i);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Result of it's execution:

100

0

How on Earth `i` was changed? So [sprintf()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) can change input variables? Why?

Comment: undefined behaviour is undefined => dupe of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's UB.

Looks like `i` is allocated right after `c`. When you `sprintf` "100" it's actually changes 4 bytes, including `\0` terminator. So it overwrites `i`.

Answer (score 3):

> *"How on Earth `i` was changed?"*

**[Undefined behaviour.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**

To elaborate, in the second case, the destination buffer does not have a space to store the terminating null character, thereby the access is made past the valid memory, causing undefined behaviour.

Quoting the `sprintf()` behaviour (from `C11`, chapter 7.21.6.6, emphasis mine)

> *"The `sprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by the argument s) rather than to a stream. **A null character is written at the end of the characters written;** it is not counted as part of the returned value."*

So, while using the function, you need to ensure that the destination buffer is long enough to hold the required value, plus a null terminator.